# ListView will only display the initial items

Tags: android, listview

I'm attempting to use a custom ArrayAdapter for a listView in which I have in one of my activities. The quantity of data I am using is quite large, so to rule out that being the issue I hardcoded an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to simply pass 8 items to display on my listView, however the same issue has occured where only the initial 4 are being displayed with no ability to scroll to further items.

I am also aware that there are currently no images being displayed on the listView, I intend to link this up after resolving this issue.

This is the main activity which will display the listView in question:

**ProductSelectionActivity.java**

```
public class ProductSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView productListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_selection);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> productsList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> prodIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> prodNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> prodCosts = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> prodMainImages = new ArrayList<String>();

    prodIds.add("id1");
    prodIds.add("id2");
    prodIds.add("id3");
    prodIds.add("id4");
    prodIds.add("id5");
    prodIds.add("id6");
    prodIds.add("id7");
    prodIds.add("id8");

    prodNames.add("name1");
    prodNames.add("name2");
    prodNames.add("name3");
    prodNames.add("name4");
    prodNames.add("name5");
    prodNames.add("name6");
    prodNames.add("name7");
    prodNames.add("name8");

    prodCosts.add("cost1");
    prodCosts.add("cost2");
    prodCosts.add("cost3");
    prodCosts.add("cost4");
    prodCosts.add("cost5");
    prodCosts.add("cost6");
    prodCosts.add("cost7");
    prodCosts.add("cost8");

    prodMainImages.add("image1");
    prodMainImages.add("image2");
    prodMainImages.add("image3");
    prodMainImages.add("image4");
    prodMainImages.add("image5");
    prodMainImages.add("image6");
    prodMainImages.add("image7");
    prodMainImages.add("image8");

    productsList.add(prodIds);
    productsList.add(prodNames);
    productsList.add(prodCosts);
    productsList.add(prodMainImages);

    // Create the listView arrayAdapter
    ProductListAdapter arrayAdapter =
            new ProductListAdapter(this, R.layout.product_list_items, productsList);
    // Set the adapter
    productListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.products_list);
    productListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

}}
```

The following is the class for the adapter:

**ProductListAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>> {

// Initialise list of products
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> products;

public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    products = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_list_items, parent, false);
    }

    // Get product listing info with reference to position that has been passed as param
    ArrayList<String> prodIds = products.get(0);
    String prodId = prodIds.get(position);

    ArrayList<String> prodNames = products.get(1);
    String prodName = prodNames.get(position);

    ArrayList<String> prodCosts = products.get(2);
    String prodCost = prodCosts.get(position);

    ArrayList<String> prodMainImages = products.get(3);
    String prodMainImage = prodMainImages.get(position);

    // Getting id for textview and imageview
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_name_text);
    TextView textViewCost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_cost_text);

    // Setting values to ids
    textViewName.setText(prodName);
    textViewCost.setText("£"+prodCost);

    return convertView;
}}
```

The layout for the ProductSelectionActivity:

**activity_product_selection.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductSelectionActivity">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/products_list"
        android:layout_width="396dp"
        android:layout_height="508dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.961" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout for the adapter:

**product_list_items.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/prod_main_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        app:srcCompat="@color/background_holo_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prod_name_text"
            android:layout_width="278dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="@string/prod_name_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prod_cost_text"
            android:layout_width="278dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="@string/prod_cost_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I believe the issue lies within the layout files, through process of elimination of other factors that I thought may have been the issue; such as ensuring all data was being passed correctly (I was able to identify this through the Logcat).

If there is anything else that I could clarify then please let me know.

Comment: make product_list_items.xml's linear layout height to wrap_content

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I tried this out and although it should've been set to this, it did not resolve the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListView will display the items that you are passing in the adapter. So you are passing an ArrayList of 4 elements. This is why the ListView only shows 4 items. If you add more elements to the productsList ArrayList then the number of items you can show will increase.

Another thing, just to improve on what you are doing. Instead of creating separate ArrayLists for each product detail separately, just create a model for your Product and load it with data. Then pass a ArrayList to your custom adapter with any number of Product items you want.

```
class Product {
    String productId;
    String productName;
    String productCost;
    String productImage;

    Product(String id, String name, String cost, String image) {
        productId = id;
        productName = name;
        productCost = cost;
        productImage = image;
    }
}
```

Now in your ProductSelectionActivity just use it like this.

```
ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList();
productList.add(new Product("id1", "name1", "cost1", "image1");
//Do this for all other products

ProductListAdapter arrayAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(this, R.layout.product_list_items, productList);
// Set the adapter
productListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.products_list);
productListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The final step is to update your adapter to handle an ArrayList of Products

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {
    // Initialise list of products
    ArrayList<Product> products;

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Product> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        products = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_list_items, parent, false);
        }

        //Get the product item for this position
        Product product = products.get(0);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_name_text);
        TextView textViewCost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_cost_text);

        // Setting values to ids
        textViewName.setText(product.productName);
        textViewCost.setText("£" + product.productCost);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Another improvement would be to use a ViewHolder instead of using a simple view.

Comment: Brilliant answer, really cleared up my confusion with what was going wrong as I completely missed how the position param was being used. Works near perfectly, with one minor thing within the adapter class, the getting of the product item line would need to read Product product = products.get(position);

Comment: As for the ViewHolder, I will need to look into this I believe as my next step will be to load the images also, and I wouldn't want them all trying to load at once -  if correct I believe ViewHolder would allow only what has been viewed to be cached in memory?

Comment: @LukeBeveridge it would be better if you look into RecyclerView. It is almost identical in use to a ListView and will help you with what you just mentioned about the images being loaded in memory.

Comment: I've been reading the other answers and comments also and they are saying similar about the RecyclerView, will most likely be the way I shall be headed with this, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Wrapper(POJO) class to hold your product information and use it for your list adapter. It would be a better way to handle by you list rather than using `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

First create a model(Pojo) class to hold product information.

```
class Product {

    String prodId;
    String prodName;
    String prodCost;
    String prodMainImage;

    public Product(String prodIds, String prodNames, String prodCostsl, String prodMainImages) {
        this.prodId = prodIds;
        this.prodName = prodNames;
        this.prodCost = prodCostsl;
        this.prodMainImage = prodMainImages;
    }
}
```

ProductSelectionActivity.java

```
public class ProductSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView productListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_selection);

    ArrayList<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

    productsList.add(new Product("id1", "name1", "cost1", "image1"));
    productsList.add(new Product("id2", "name2", "cost2", "image2"));
    productsList.add(new Product("id3", "name3", "cost3", "image3"));
    productsList.add(new Product("id4", "name4", "cost4", "image4"));

    ProductListAdapter arrayAdapter =
            new ProductListAdapter(this, R.layout.product_list_items, productsList);
    // Set the adapter
    productListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.products_list);
    productListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}}
```

ProductListAdapter.java

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    // Initialise list of products
    ArrayList<Product> products;

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Product> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        products = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_list_items, parent, false);
        }

        Product product = products.get(position);

        // Getting id for textview and imageview
        TextView textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_name_text);
        TextView textViewCost = convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_cost_text);

        // Setting values to ids
        textViewName.setText(product.prodName);
        textViewCost.setText("£"+product.prodCost);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

That's it. It should work properly. Although nowadays, RecyclerView is being used more for its performance and management. This code can be replaced with RecyclerView as well. Let me know if you want to convert it to RecyclerView. I can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Man, first of all use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) and don't worry about size of data. Secondly make a class which will contains your data:

```
class Data {
    int id;
    String name;
    String imageUrl;

    public Data(int id, String name, String imageUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Please, research information about how to use RecyclerView and why RecyclerView is better that ListView.

Comment: I'll need to look into whether RecyclerView fits my needs for the next stage of this project, but would it work similarly to a listView (where is would be allowed it's own custom implementation?)

Answer (score 0):

Set **wrap_content** to the height of root layout in product_list_items layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/prod_main_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    app:srcCompat="@color/background_holo_light" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_name_text"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/prod_name_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_cost_text"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/prod_cost_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```